# Error when starting BitCoin

Tags: installation, database, bitcoin

I just installed Bitcoin and everything seemed to be going well. After a few days the client stopped loading at boot and instead gave this error:

> DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run
>   database recovery        bitcoin in
>   CMyApp::OnUnhandledException()

Anyone know how I can run the db recovery or other ways to rectify the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarise the conclusion of that thread, you should begin by making a full backup.  Then, once you are sure your backup is secure, you can delete everything **except** the `wallet.dat` file in the `~/.bitcoin` folder.  This will cause BitCoin to re-download the block chain and restore the local block database.  Don't panic if it initially shows a zero balance after restarting--it won't show your correct balance until it's downloaded the relevant blocks.

On a side note, this is also the safest way to perform an upgrade to a new version of the BitCoin software--*backup everything*, then delete everything except the `wallet.dat` file.  When you run the new version of bitcoin, your balance will appear once it finishes downloading the blockchain.

Don't forget to head over to the [BitCoin StackExchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30763/bitcoin) to lend your support and vote on sample questions!  It would be great to have a single place for BitCoin Q&A across multiple platforms and scenarios.

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: I suggest you also remind people to be very careful with how they backup wallet.dat.  It generally contains keys for both current and 100 **future** bitcoin addresses, and it is not (yet) encrypted.  Best practice is to have a "checking" wallet with a small working balance, and a carefully secured "savings" wallet for the rest.  See [Securing your wallet - Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet)

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: Before doing anything, backup your Bitcoin files! Especially wallet.dat!

Then, checkout this forum thread:
http://www.bitcoin.org/smf/index.php?topic=1993.0